# Asking multiple separate topics in one question

Tags: discussion, community-guidelines

These type of [question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/3065/172) are not good in my opinion since

1. OP has not clearly mentioned about the core issue
2. OP has asked different questions on one question, answering all the parts would be time consuming
3. People will be hesitant to answer in case they just know the answer for part of the question.
4. Looking at the initial response from community OP got encouraged to for posting multi-part question and has updated his question with more set of questions.

IMO asking multiple separate topics/questions in one question is wrong. Need suggestions on this and needs to be added to scope of "Sitecore questions anyone can ask here" if any not already added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### My Thoughts

While multi-part questions are encouraged, IMHO posting multiple separate questions in the same post - that is, questions that are not all sub-parts of the same question and could be asked in a separate post - should be discouraged. I see three separate topics/questions in the linked post. I believe that these should have been added as three separate topic/question posts.

#### Multi-part vs multi-topic

I ask a lot of multi-part questions, and I think that @HarshBaid did a good job of identifying that the issue here is not *multi-**part*** questions, but rather *multi-**topic*** questions.

#### Discouraging this practice

To add to @HarshBaid's list, including multiple questions that are totally independent of one another in the same post can also make it very difficult for future users to find the information that they are looking for.

I agree that as community members, we should try to discourage this practice, but I do not believe that in this particular case the comments led the OP to add additional quesitons, as those questions were also included in the post that the OP copied from on StackOverflow. Regardless, I do believe that we should do what we can to inform members that this practice should be discouraged.

Answer (score 3):

i agree, these should be all separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, in case anyone is wondering. And I like the distinction being identified here, between multi-topic and multi-part questions - very astute :-)

But I also see 2 people venturing forth to answer the question in question (ehh) and only 4 close votes in a community of over 1200.

While it would be simple for us mods to "rule" on such matters, it really should be a community effort. Which is why you won't see us stepping in on specific cases such as this one.

I might add; it does feel a bit like a lot of the community took a step back when we mods were appointed. It should actually be the other way around ;-)